# jade dosen't display image in route with param

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm using expres 4 and I have images in uploads folders

My code is

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/uploads'));

 //it works
    app.route('/')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        Post.find({},null,{sort:{'created_at':-1}}).populate('created_by').exec(function(err, posts) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.render('blog',{
                title: 'Blog',
                posts: posts
            })
        });
    });
    //it doesn't work
    app.route('/post/:id_post')
        .get(function (req, res) {
            Post.findOne({_id:req.params.id_post}).populate('created_by').exec(function(err, post) {
                if (err) throw err;
                res.render('detail',{
                    title: 'Post',
                    post: post
                })
            });
        });
```

my Jade is

```
img(src='#{post.image}')
```

In both template, the same image, but When I visit the route `/` I can see the image, when visit `/post/:id_post` I don't see the image

Comment: Can you post the template?

Comment: Try `img(src='/#{post.image}')` (notice the leading forward slash `='/…`)

Comment: @laggingreflex it works, can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A relative link with a leading forward slash starts from the site **root**, whereas without which it starts from the current level.

If you have a link `src='image.jpg'` and it's on your home `/` page then the URL is fetched as http://example.com/image.jpg

But if the same link `src='image.jpg'` is on some `/other` page then the URL is fetched as http://example.com/other/image.jpg (relative to the *current* (/other) level page)

Alternatively if you have a link `src='/image.jpg'` (with a **leading forward slash**) then the URL is **always** fetched as http://example.com/image.jpg (relative to the **root** of your site)